# Changing entity-classes problem with development for app-engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, refactoring, nosql, datastore

My problem is pretty much obvious:

1. I had a class named `TaskDescription` which corresponded to a kind (table) in App Engine Datastore. 
   Then I've renamed it to `TaskContent` and all stored data is seems to be lost now (because class name which is the so-called `kind` name is a part of the path to the stored data).
2. I realize that almost the same problem will occur every time I rename a single field in any entity-class.

Nothing is perfect in this world and I have doubts that it's possible to create all and absolutely correct entities from scratch and never change them after that.

So, how to deal with this issue?

Comment: What API are you using? JDO? JPA? low-level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways:

1. Leave Entities as they are and change the mapping: in objectify you can set the [entity to class name mapping](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/AnnotationReference): e.g. @Entity(name="EntityName").
2. Change Entities in the datastore: as datastore is schemaless this can not be done with a simple command. For Entity name change you need to create a new entity, copy all properties and delete the old entity. People usually use a [MapReduce jobs to perform datastore maintenance](http://www.learningtechnicalstuff.com/2010/06/maintaining-app-engine-datastore-with.html). Here's [MapReduce for java](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInJava).

For field name changes objectify has explicit [support for migrating schemas](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Migrating_Schemas) (there is no schemas, but they still call it that way).